# Which is the proper implementation of ASPNET Identity when the store doesn't support async method?

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-identity

I'm new on the ASP.NET Identity 2.1 and also the async/await programming.

I'd like to integrate ASP.NET Identity with my user store, which doesn't support 'async' method, specifically, Telerik's OpenAccess.

In the ASP.NET Identity, all the `IUserStore` interfaces (and other IXXXStores) are expose only `~Async` methods. It seems that they are strongly encourage to implement code runs asynchronously. Unfortunately, Telerik's OpenAccess doesn't support `~Async` version of methods, so I have to implement it by myself.

I've searched several examples, and I found that many of them(which doesn't support `~Async`) were like this:

```
public Task<AspNetUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId)) throw new ArgumentException("userId");

    var user = this.Context.AspNetUsers.Where(o => o.Id == userId).SingleOrDefault();
    return Task.FromResult<AspNetUser>(user);
}
```

It doesn't seem to be proper asynchronous code. Of course find user by key might be fast enough. But since it has a network I/O, shouldn't it be like follow?

```
public Task<AspNetUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId)) throw new ArgumentException("userId");

    return Task.Run(() =>
        this.Context.AspNetUsers.Where(o => o.Id == userId).SingleOrDefault()
    ).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I'm not sure just wrapping synchronous code by `Task.Run` makes it proper `~Async` method.
Neither what's difference between above and below:

```
public async Task<AspNetUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId)) throw new ArgumentException("userId");

    return await Task.Run(() =>
        this.Context.AspNetUsers.Where(o => o.Id == userId).SingleOrDefault()
    ).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Which is the proper way can be? Or is there other way to implement ASP.NET Identity with those stores doesn't support native `~Async` method?

Comment: No, those simple implementations are not "proper async"... but do keep in mind lots of projects (both legacy and recent) don't use the async/await paradigm *anywhere*, and having an interface of an *identity* provider force it upon the project is often considered unwelcome and pushy. Hence the "you may call it async, but we'll implement it like the other 98% of our codebase anyway" approach.

Comment: Thanks for comment. These `UserStore` Interfaces are consumed by AspNet `UserManager`, not my own code. It(`UserManager`) might call my implementations with asynchronous expectation. In other words, if a library force to extend it in asynchronous manner, how do I implement properly?

Comment: Indeed, your question stands! I was just commenting on the origin of those typical non-async implementations you encountered (from experience).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that `TaskFactory.FromResult` is not proper asynchronous code, especially since the underlying API is doing I/O-bound operations (which are a perfect match for async). However, there *isn't* a way to force a non-async API to be an async API; you just have to ask Telerik to fix their API.

In the meantime, either approach you mentioned would work, but the `TaskFactory.FromResult` approach is superior. As a general rule, you should avoid `Task.Run` on ASP.NET because it will unnecessarily interfere with the thread pool.

The [asynchronous convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) will work just fine when a task is synchronously completed. It isn't ideal, of course, that the method is *blocking* instead of asynchronous, but it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I felt uncomfortable non-async API in the async method, but it seems that I have to take it until async API available.

Comment: @GongdoGong: You've got the right mentality. Your code is working around a shortcoming of the Telerik API. Unfortunate but unavoidable.